# Flutter Error: Operation not permitted in linux

Tags: flutter

I try to code using flutter in my linux and connect to my android. I use "flutter create" to make new project and then i try using "flutter run" but i got crash and when i check log:

FileSystemException: FileSystemException: Failed to set file modification time, path = '/home/whoami/opt/projectku/flutter_project_1/.packages' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

i'm new learning flutter and reading issue in github make me confused. so, if anyone know the answer please help me :)

Answer (score 2):

Flutter does not have the right to make changes to the .packages file in your Project directory.

1) Open the terminal, type in the command: sudo nautilus

2) It will open the file explorer in root authority mode

3) Go to your project directory, right click on the .packages file and change the ownership so that all groups have "Read and Write" privileges

4) Run again

This might have happened because you previously created this file under root access, or ran Android Studio using root access (or sudo).

Let me know if that works.